# Debug VisualStudio in tablet instead of desktop

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, model-view-controller, tablet, nopcommerce

My question might be silly but I'm new and I really need help.

I am making some changes to a nopCommerce site in VisualStudio. When I hit run in Google Chrome it starts on localhost:number and I can debug from my pc (meaning break points are hit when I go to specific pages).

What I need to do is debug my site while connecting to it from my tablet instead of my pc.

I think I can do that. Can someone tell me how?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx - this will give you the nuts and bolts of what you need to do. Once you change the IIS Express settings and set up a host header, you can debug from any device that connects to the internet from the same subnet where IIS Express is. PS -- do the "Ninja" way, not the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but the following link will give you the nuts and bolts of what you need to do in order to achieve what you are after:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Make sure you do the Ninja way, not the easy way.

After configuring the IIS Express settings and setting up the host header, you can debug from any device that connects to the internet from the same subnet where IIS Express is. You can ignore everything else that has to do with setting up the self-signed SSL certificate and serving up content over port 443, it sounds like all you want is port 80.